# Feed Dialog with Page Feed

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-page

on my webpage I have integrated the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) using the JavaScript SDK. It works all like a charm, except when I'm using Facebook as a page.

I get this error message:

> You are using Facebook as myPage
>
> To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

I already tried to change the `from` and `to` parameters, but with no luck.

Is there any way to post a story on a page with the Feed Dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this dialog is not supported when you are using Facebook as a Page.  Please use Graph API -> Post (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: Do you have a source on facebook.com for this? It seems to not work for me either but I can't find a definitive source

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact do this.  Just follow the instructions as it says and switch to using Facebook as yourself.

Then when you share as yourself, you can choose to share it to a "Page you manage" using the dropdown in the top-left.

[image]